# unable to call express app.post using react function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm using express with react and firebase. So currently I'm unable to push to firebase because react function is not calling app.post in my servers.js. Here is the code for my index.js.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.callApi("Accessories")
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                productAccessories: this.snapshotToArray(res.data),

            }, () => {
                this.setState({
                    productAccessories: this.addCategory("category", "Accessories", "productAccessories")
                }, () => {
                    this.setState({
                        products: this.state.productMen.concat(this.state.productKid, this.state.productWomen, this.state.productAccessories),
                    }, () => {
                        this.setState({
                            productsToPush: this.filterProducts()
                        },()=>{
                            this.push()
                        })
                    });
                })
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
}
```

as you can see I tried to call the push function only after my productTopush are filled.

here is my code for my push function

```
push() {
    var d = new Date();
    var today = d.getDate() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getFullYear()
    var updateData = {
        top4: this.state.productsToPush,
        date: today
    }
    console.log(this.state.productsToPush);
    this.postApi('/api/post/top', updateData)
        .then(res => {
            //console.log(res.data);
        })
    console.log('pushing really hard bro')
}
```

here is my servers.js

```
    app.post('/api/post/top',(req,res) =>{
    console.log("top4 works")
    var ref=db.ref('/Top')
    ref.push(req.body.data)
    console.log("top 4 really does works")
})
```

this is my callApi function:

```
    callApi = async (category) => {

    const response = await fetch('/api/get/products/' + category);
    const body = await response.json();

    if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

    return body;
};
```

so my push function is actually called but it just doesn't call the server.js

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT:  ok here's the weirdest thing, it actually pushed into firebase but it seems to only work like 1/20 times. I did not change anything.

Comment: What does your `callApi` function look like?

Comment: i've added it into my code above

Comment: Did you try calling the express API via `curl` or postman or something similar to see if the API is working in the first place?

Comment: before every `post` request, there is an `options` request to server. You need to use something like `app.options("*", function(...`. This is used to get `CORS` info and to also check if post method is allowed to server.

Comment: yes i can confirm that the API and post method is allowed

Comment: @LucasTan Is there an `app.options("/api/post/top", ...` or `app.options("*", ...` ? Like I said in my previous comment, an options request is sent first. Can you also check the browser console for errors?